# Not able to share static resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, static, staticresource

I'm studing spring by YouTube guides) Resenty i tryied to start my own project, and got some issue. Resources from directory /static/** isn't provided to outer world - 404 error.
/Static/ located in /src/main/resources/

I tried:
add

```
spring.resources.static-locations=/js/,/css/
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/static/css/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.css
```

in application.properties - no changes.

When i add

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("file:///"+uploadPath+"/");
```

to 
   `public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)`

- files from upload path shares perfectly.

If i add .js file to /static/ or /static/js IDEA normally links the calls from my code to the scripts. But scripts don't work, when application started.

```
@Configuration

public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

    }

    @Override

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")

                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }}


    WebSecurityConfig

    @Configuration

    @EnableWebSecurity

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/users","/static/**").permitAll()

                //.anyRequest().authenticated()

                .anyRequest().permitAll()

                    .and()

                .formLogin()

                .loginPage("/login")

                .permitAll()

                    .and()

                .rememberMe()

                    .and()

                .logout()

                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
    Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userService)

                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/banking

    spring.session.store-type=jdbc

    spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

    spring.datasource.username=postgres

    spring.datasource.password=123456

    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

    spring.jpa.show-sql=true

    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

    spring.freemarker.expose-request-attributes=true
```

**project structure**

```
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───web
│   │       ├───configs
│   │       ├───controllers
│   │       ├───domain
│   │       ├───Repositories
│   │       ├───service
│   │       └───validator
│   └───resources
│       └───templates
│           ├───parts
│           └───static
│               ├───css
│               └───js
└───test
    └───java
```

Comment: Hi , could you share your folder structure?

Comment: Hello. Added one.

Comment: If you are using spring boot 
you need to place your folder structure to src/main/resources/static 
It by default searches there 
and please remove all additional configs what you have done

Comment: So src/main/resources/templates/static/js should be moved to 
src/main/resources/static/js
Plese try and let me know

Comment: Great thx to everybody. You are right, i had to place static folder upper in resource path. Dont know why, but i was sure, that Spring try to find all directories with name static and share it)

Comment: Added answer , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please just move your directories from

```
 src/main/resources/templates/static/
```

to

```
 src/main/resources/static/
```

By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a folder called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext

Thanks